# Custom attribute name without value - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-Vue Accordions in my project, and I want to dynamically render a loop of accordions.
The problem is that it has an attribute `v-b-toggle.accordionName`, which has no value (or this is what I think).

I need to find a way to bind this attribute's 'name' dynamically.

```
<b-card no-body v-for="seminar in seminars" :key="seminar.name">

  <b-card-header role="tab">
    <b-button block v-b-toggle.( ?? )>{{seminar.title}}</b-button>
  </b-card-header>

  <b-collapse :id="seminar.name" role="tabpanel">
    <b-card-body>
      Hey there!
    </b-card-body>
  </b-collapse>

</b-card>
```

I tried to use `v-b-toggle.seminar.name`, but clearly failed.
Also tried to use v-bind="toggle", and have a data of `toggle={'v-b-toggle.seminarOne': true}`, but also failed.

Finally, I know it can be done using custom directives, but I am looking for another local way, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `v-b-toggle` attribute is already dynamic. you can simply use it like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
   seminars:[
          {
              title:'seminar1',
              name:'seminar1',
          },
          {
              title:'seminar2',
              name:'seminar2',
        }
      ]
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.14/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@next/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.14/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">
<b-card no-body v-for="seminar in seminars" :key="seminar.name">

  <b-card-header role="tab">
    <b-button block v-b-toggle="seminar.name">{{seminar.title}}</b-button>
  </b-card-header>

  <b-collapse :id="seminar.name" role="tabpanel">
    <b-card-body>
      Hey there! i am {{seminar.name}}
    </b-card-body>
  </b-collapse>

</b-card>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aep6hqd1/3/